# Android Studio. Can't accept ImageView size from styles

Tags: android, imageview, styles

Style for ImageView I have created

```
<style name="HelpSectionImage" >
    <item name="android:layout_width">24dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">24dp</item>
    <item name="android:padding">3dp</item>
</style>
```

This style assigned to ImageView. 
Padding is working. layout_width, layout_height not working.
Have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `Dimention` resource as XML file:

```
<resources>
  <dimen name="android_layout_width">24dp</dimen>
  <dimen name="android_layout_height">24dp</dimen>
  <dimen name="android_padding">3dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

when use it, just call `R.dimen.dimen_name` or use `@dimen/dimen_name` in xml